# Dictionary to dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to convert to a 3-column Data Frame.

```
dict= {(0, 367): 0.0,
 (2, 6): 0.0,
 (2, 4): 0.0,
 (2, 3): 0.0,
 (2, 1): 0.0,
 (5, 6): 0.0,
 (5, 263): 0.0}
```

What I tried:

```
pd.DataFrame(results)
```

error I get:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Expected result

```
col1 col2 col3
0 367 0.0
2 6 0.0
2 4 0.0
2 3 0.0
2 1 0.0
5 6 0.0
5 263 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to create a DataFrame containing all values, not only first two:

```py
dct = {
    (0, 367): 0.0,
    (2, 6): 0.0,
    (2, 4): 0.0,
    (2, 3): 0.0,
    (2, 1): 0.0,
    (5, 6): 0.0,
    (5, 263): 0.0,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[*k, v] for k, v in dct.items()], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     0   367   0.0
1     2     6   0.0
2     2     4   0.0
3     2     3   0.0
4     2     1   0.0
5     5     6   0.0
6     5   263   0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option nesting `result` to make it a Multi-Index column then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas-dataframe-reset-index) and change the column names:

```
results = {(0, 367): 0.0,
           (2, 6): 0.0,
           (2, 4): 0.0,
           (2, 3): 0.0,
           (2, 1): 0.0,
           (5, 6): 0.0,
           (5, 263): 0.0}

df = pd.DataFrame({'col3': results}).reset_index()
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

`df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     0   367   0.0
1     2     1   0.0
2     2     3   0.0
3     2     4   0.0
4     2     6   0.0
5     5     6   0.0
6     5   263   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Series`

```
pd.Series(d).reset_index()
Out[140]: 
   level_0  level_1    0
0        0      367  0.0
1        2        6  0.0
2        2        4  0.0
3        2        3  0.0
4        2        1  0.0
5        5        6  0.0
6        5      263  0.0
```